# How can I check an int value while i'm increasing that value from another script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

in my Unity scene I'm trying to activate a portal animation when you pick up all the coins on that level, but the problem is that my portal script does not detect when the coin counter value is equal to 6 (that's the total number of coins in that level).

I have this script which is the script that is attached to the coins and increases the coin counter value.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MonedaScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject moneda;
    public AudioClip clip;
    public Vector3 PosicionMoneda;

    public void Update ()
    {
        transform.Rotate (0, 90 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "Player")
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, PosicionMoneda, 1f);
            AparecerPortalNivel9.ContadorMonedas += 1;
            Destroy(moneda);
        }
    }
}
```

And then i have the portal script which sould detect ewhen you pick all the coins. It is attached to the `PanelPortal` gameobject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AparecerPortalNivel9 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public GameObject PanelPortal;
    //public ScoringSystem SS;
    public bool DeberiaAparecer = true;
    public static int ContadorMonedas;

    void Start()
    {
        //SS = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SistemaDeScore").GetComponent; ScoringSystem();
        PanelPortal.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (ContadorMonedas == 6f)
        {
            Debug.Log("FuncionaHostia");
            PanelPortal.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            anim.SetBool("Aparecer",true);
            DeberiaAparecer = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me on what should i do so my portal script detects when the coins picked up are 6 and then run all the functions inside the IF method?

Thanks everyone

Comment: I think there's a duplicate for this somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Draco18s I had the same experience 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MonoBehaviour`'s `Update` will never run while the gameobject it is on is disabled.

Because `AparecerPortalNivel9` is attached to `PanelPortal`, when you do this you are preventing the `Update` method from being called:

```
PanelPortal.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

The easiest solution here is to move `AparecerPortalNivel9` to a different gameobject.

Comment: I know its a dumb question but im new on this but i didn't realised. Thx <3

Comment: @Rasty Happy to help! Don't forget to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted by clicking the grey check mark (✔) to the left. It helps people on the search page see that the answer was answered and gives me some reputation points :)  [See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)